# Scrolling TrackBar to display my chart in realtime

Tags: c#, winforms, charts, trackbar

I want to display a chart in realtime.

[image]

My method is by adding the DataPoint as the TrackBar scrolls.

```
private void trackBar1_Scroll(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (trackBar1.Value < valueBefore) //scrolling to the left removes previous DataPoint
    {
        try
        {
            chart1.Series["Correlation"].Points.RemoveAt(valueBefore);
        }
        catch
        {
            MessageBox.Show(valueBefore.ToString()); //Try catch for debugging purposes
        }   
    }

    else //scrolling to the right adds DataPoint based on trackBar's current value
    {
        chart1.Series["Correlation"].Points.AddXY(Convert.ToDouble(age[trackBar1.Value]), salary[trackBar1.Value]);
    }

    valueBefore = trackBar1.Value; //in order to know which 

    label1.Text = "No. of records : " + (trackBar1.Value + 1);

}
```

The code works if I use my arrow keys or mouse clicks (SmallChange and LargeChange defined to 1).

Scrolling to the right causes no issue, however scrolling back to the left would cause an exception error which I am unable to figure out. It seems that the `valueBefore` for my DataPoint index is out of range as so:

```
System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException was unhandled
  HResult=-2146233086
  Message=Index was out of range. Must be non-negative and less than the size of the collection.
Parameter name: index
  ParamName=index
  Source=mscorlib
```

How do I solve this?

Answer (score 0):

The `DataPointCollection.RemoveAt(int)` method is inherited from Collection and will remove a point based on the index which refers to the current state of the DataPointCollection, not your data.

Try placing a breakpoint at the line that throws the exception and inspecting the `chart1.Series["Correlation"].Points` collection. This should allow you to see what's going on.